# Maximum number of edges in a planar graph without $3$- or $4$-cycles

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

> What is the largest possible number of edges in a planar graph without $3$- or $4$-cycles?

I've been unsuccessfully trying to solve this problem from my book. I know that every planar graph without $3$-cycles has at most $2n - 4$ edges, though I'm not sure about graphs without $4$-cycles.

Comment: Look at how you proved the $2n-4$ bound. This proof generalizes.

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition for the absence of $3-$ and $4-$cycles is that every facet of the planar graph is a polygon with $\geq 5$ sides. Does Euler's formula tell you something?

Answer (score 3):

If a planar graph $G$ contains no $3$- or $4$-cycles, then given a planar embedding of $G$, every face is bounded by at least $5$ edges. Then since every edges is incident to exactly two faces, we have $5f \leq 2e$. Combining this with Euler's characteristic formula,

$$\begin{align}
  f-e+n = 2 &\implies 5f-5e+5n = 10 \\
            &\implies 2e-5e+5n \geq 10 \\
            &\implies 5n-10 \geq 3e \\\\
            &\implies e \leq \left\lfloor\frac{5n-10}{3}\right\rfloor
\end{align}$$