# Maximum number of edges of a planar graph without cycles of length 3 and 4

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I'm trying to calculate the maximum number of edges in a planar graph without cycles of length $3$ and $4$ (thus, $C_3$ and $C_4$). I've assumed that the condition is that the length of each face has to be at least $5$.

I've written that $2m \leq 5f$ (m - number of edges, f - number of faces) and then I've used Euler's formula for faces, $f=m-n+2$. At the end I got that $3m \leq 5n-10$ is the maximum number of edges that a planar graph can have if it doesn't have a cycles of length 3 and 4.

Is this correct? Am I doing something wrong? Could someone please comment?

Comment: Same problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589771/maximum-edges-in-a-planar-graph-without-3-and-4-cycles (currently with no answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine to me. Note that it shows Petersen is not planar and is tight for the dodecahedron, as it should be.